# Substitute pattern on a line containing another pattern

Tags: sed, pattern-matching, substitution

says file has

```
ABC DEF ,No
IMD DEF ,NO
ANC KOJD ,NO
ABC MSL ,NO
```

How do I use sed to substitute `,No` with `XYZ,No` only on lines containing `ABC`?

So final output is

```
ABC DEF XYZ ,No
IMD DEF ,NO
ANC KOJD ,NO
ABC MSL XYZ,NO
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
sed -r '/ABC/s/(,N[oO])/XYZ\1/' file
```

This uses `sed '/pattern/s/find/replace/' file`, which does the replacement `s/find/replace/` in all lines containing `pattern`.

In this case, we catch `,No` because it can be either upper or lowercase, so that it is printed back.

#### Test

```
$ sed -r '/ABC/s/(,N[oO])/XYZ\1/' a
ABC DEF XYZ,No
IMD DEF ,NO
ANC KOJD ,NO
ABC MSL XYZ,NO
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/ABC/s/,no/XYZ &/i' file
```

This caters for all cases of `no`, however if the you want to cater for only `No` or `NO` use:

```
sed '/ABC/s/,N[oO]/XYZ &/' file
```